# Cannot connect Samsung Galaxy A9 to Unity via Unity Remote 5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

What's done:

- Enabled Developer settings and USB debugging.
- Downloaded and installed SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.
  BTW, in the Device Manager I can see that winusb.sys provided by Microsoft is used for Samsung Android ADB Interface. Is it okay?

[image: Samsung Android ADB Interface driver files]

- In Unity set up "Unity Remote->Device" to "Any Android Device"
- Restarted adb server(adb kill-server/start-server), computer, phone, Unity many times.
- I can see my phone in adb devices:

> C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.13f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools>adb
>   devices List of devices attached
>   2a44edd8xxxxxxxx        device

- Tried different versions of Unity.
  In all cases a game is not shown in Unity Remote 5. I wonder is there any log which I could see Unity tries to connect to a device in?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem:
[image: SDK paths]

I just unchecked "Android SDK tools" and filled up the path manually.